# VBA for...next loop with byte data type not supported?

Tags: vba

Why do I get error 6 "overflow" with this code? I'm confused..

```
Sub test()
    Dim i as byte
    For i = 3 To 2 step - 1
        Debug.Print i
    Next
End Sub
```

The same with type integer works.

Comment: Seems to only be when stepping backwards `Step -x`. Interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, the `step` is also of type [`Byte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byte-data-type) and bytes can only be 0 ... 255, hence the overflow.  The same occurs if you simply do

```
dim i as byte
i = -1
```

or even with

```
For i = 200 To 255
    Debug.Print i
Next
```

as, at the end of the last loop, `i` is incremented in the `next` statement before doing the comparison (`<=255`) and this incrementation leads to an overflow error.

Comment: Nice answer. Good addition to this is: [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). This is very likely to happen with `Bytes` too, so there is no good reason to use `Byte` or `Integer` at all in VBA.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ the only good reason to use bytes is when converting strings to byte, since then the operations are numeric and therefore faster (for example implementing the levenshtein distance).

Comment: @MGP Yes, you are right I should have written *"almost no good reason"* ;) There are always those edge cases where it is actually useful. But most users won't ever want to use `Byte`, for example in the case of the example I would never use a `Byte`.